Нужна ли запятая после "чужим"?
Теперь Кристоффер с женой Майей должны приехать в незнакомую страну и уладить все дела родного, но так и оставшегося для сына чужим (?) человека.

В качестве варианта:
Теперь Кристоффер с женой Майей должны приехать в незнакомую страну и уладить все дела родного, хотя так и оставшегося для сына чужим, человека.
Пояснение

Обособление распространенного оборота желательно для лучшего понимания  структуры предложения, но обороты с противительным союзом НО обычно не обособляются.  Поэтому желательно использовать союз ХОТЯ.

Тогда оборот обособляется по образцу присоединительных конструкций:  Раздались крики разносчиков, продающих всякие, даже русские, журналы (Т.); Розенталь, пункт 1.


Из темы Хотя и обособляется?
Все наши участки вместе с сообществом растений — объекты живые, развивающиеся по своим законам, в которых есть и конкурентная борьба, и строгие предпочтения, и железная, хотя и не всегда понятная человеку непосвящённому, логика.

А если оставить НО, то обособлять не надо?

Да, тогда не надо обособлять. Это однородные отношения. Что касается союза ХОТЯ, то там факультативное решение (однородные или присоединительные).
